# Why is writing to firebase database not executed?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In this code , writing to database is executed only for the last item(out of 9 items) .. 
all logs in the code display normally ... translation is executed and returned in log correctly for all items. 
Only write to firebase database is not executed except for last item .  is it something related to calling the updatechildern from within the translator code ?

```
  myRef
     .limitToFirst(1)
     .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    final Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator1 = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                    do {
                        DataSnapshot ds = iterator1.next();
                        iteratorkey = ds.getKey();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Current key is : " + iteratorkey);

                        Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator2 = ds.getChildren().iterator();

                        do {

                            item = iterator2.next().getValue(Item.class);

                            englishArabicTranslator.translate(item.getLang())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                                            new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String translatedText) {
                                                    // Translation successful.
                                                    myhashmap.clear();
                                                    Log.e(TAG, " translation successful " + translatedText);
                                                    myhashmap.put("translation", translatedText);
                                                    myhashmap.put("iteratorkey", iteratorkey);
                                                    myhashmap.put("number", item.getNum());

                                                    thelist.add(myhashmap);

                                                    Log.e(TAG, " the list :  " + thelist.size());

                                                   HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                                    map.put("base", translatedText);

                                                   //Write to database 
                                                           myRef
                                                            .child(iteratorkey).child(item.getNum()).updateChildren(map);
                                                }
                                            })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(
                                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    // Error.
                                                    // ...
                                                    Log.e(TAG, "error in translation");
                                                }
                                            });

                        } while (iterator2.hasNext());
                        textView.append(iteratorkey + "\n");

                    } while (iterator1.hasNext());
                    Log.e(TAG, " A the list size :  " + thelist.size());
                }
                Log.e(TAG, " B the list size :  " + thelist.size());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The listener was not the problem, I actually wanted to retrieve the data only once. Because I am editing the same data I am retrieving.

The problem is that firebase writes to the same child always. Thats why I thought that only the last item is modified . 
When I call the item number

```
 item.getNum()
```

It will always be the last value retrieved, Maybe someone can explain this in more and better detail.

So I just declared item final .

```
final Item item = iterator.next().getValue(Item.class);
```

Now data in firebase database is modified as intended.